# PySpark adding a column to an existing DataFrame - TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to add three calculated columns to my data frame.

The below approach doesn't work and throws an error:

> TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column: DataFrame[TicketClosedDate: timestamp] of type <class 'pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame'>. For column literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or 'create_map' function.

```py
    TAT = df.select(datediff(col('zTicketSubmitDateUTC'), col('zTicketUpdateDateUTC')).alias('TAT'))
    
    TicketClosedDate = df.select(to_timestamp(
                    when(col('TicketStatusName')=='Closed',col('TicketUpdateDate'))
                    .when(col('TicketStatusName')=='Complete',col('TicketUpdateDate'))
                    .when(col('TicketStatusName')=='Done',col('TicketUpdateDate'))
                    .otherwise('Null')
                    ).alias('TicketClosedDate'))
    
    zTicketClosedDateUTC = df.select(to_timestamp(
                    when(col('TicketStatusName')=='Closed',col('zTicketUpdateDateUTC'))
                    .when(col('TicketStatusName')=='Complete',col('zTicketUpdateDateUTC'))
                    .when(col('TicketStatusName')=='Done',col('zTicketUpdateDateUTC'))
                    .otherwise('Null')
                    ).alias('zTicketClosedDateUTC'))
    
    
    df2 = df.select(
        col('ProjectID'),
        col('TicketID'),
        col('ChildTicketID'),
        col('TicketSubmitDate'),
        col('zTicketSubmitDateUTC'),
        col('TicketUpdateDate'),
        col('zTicketUpdateDateUTC'),
        TicketClosedDate,
        zTicketClosedDateUTC,
        col('TicketStatusName'),
        col('PtgName'),
        col('TicketCategory'),
        TAT)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below. You don't need to do `df.select()` in the variables.

```
TAT = datediff(col('zTicketSubmitDateUTC'), col('zTicketUpdateDateUTC')).alias('TAT')

TicketClosedDate = to_timestamp(
                when(col('TicketStatusName')=='Closed',col('TicketUpdateDate'))
                .when(col('TicketStatusName')=='Complete',col('TicketUpdateDate'))
                .when(col('TicketStatusName')=='Done',col('TicketUpdateDate'))
                .otherwise('Null')
                ).alias('TicketClosedDate')

zTicketClosedDateUTC = to_timestamp(
                when(col('TicketStatusName')=='Closed',col('zTicketUpdateDateUTC'))
                .when(col('TicketStatusName')=='Complete',col('zTicketUpdateDateUTC'))
                .when(col('TicketStatusName')=='Done',col('zTicketUpdateDateUTC'))
                .otherwise('Null')
                ).alias('zTicketClosedDateUTC')


df2 = df.select(
    col('ProjectID'),
    col('TicketID'),
    col('ChildTicketID'),
    col('TicketSubmitDate'),
    col('zTicketSubmitDateUTC'),
    col('TicketUpdateDate'),
    col('zTicketUpdateDateUTC'),
    TicketClosedDate,
    zTicketClosedDateUTC,
    col('TicketStatusName'),
    col('PtgName'),
    col('TicketCategory'),
    TAT)
```